# How to add more parameters to wso2 identity server password reset email?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

While sending password re setting email I need to add few more parameters to the password reset link. currently "user-name", "confirmation-code" are available. Is there any way to add more parameters like tenant domain, email etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add tenant code we moved to wso2 identity server 5.1.0(milestone 6) version which support additional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it via `$IS_HOME/repository/conf/email/email-­admin-­config.xml` file. Edit this file to modify the "passwordReset" template/configuration, save the file and restart Identity Server. I have given a sample here to include an additional parameter "firstname".

```xml
<configuration type="passwordReset">
    <targetEpr></targetEpr>
    <subject>Password Reset Notification</subject>
    <body>
        Hi {first-­name}
        We received a request to change the password on the {user-­name} account
        associated with this e­mail address. If you made this request, please click
        the link below to securely change your password:


        http://localhost:9443/InfoRecoverySample/infoRecover/verify?confirmation={confirmation-code}&username={user-name}&firstname={first-­name}

        If clicking the link doesn't seem to work, you can copy and paste the link
        into your browser's address window.


        If you did not request to have your {user-­name} password reset, simply
        disregard this email and no changes to your
        account will be made.
    </body>
    <footer>
        Best Regards,
        WSO2 Carbon Team http://www.wso2.com
    </footer>
    <redirectPath></redirectPath>
</configuration>
```

Refer [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Recover+with+Notification) for more details.